# running ASP on a linux machine

Tags: linux, asp

My testing environment for coding is currently a LAMP setup on an internal server running Linux Gnome. We've recently gained 2 or so sites to do maintenance for that were written in ASP. I'm now aware I don't have a testing environment for ASP and as I know so little about what I need to do, is it possible to run ASP on a linux machine (much like you can use WAMP to run PHP on windows)?

Comment: Are you meaning "classic" ASP or ASP.NET? The two are very different kettles of fish.

Comment: unfortunately, i don't know how to tell. My ASP skills are very very low end - the website has .asp files as part of the structue. Looking at them, i'm not sure how to tell?

Comment: You can't tell just by looking at filenames. ASP.NET usually uses the file extension .aspx rather than .asp, but this is not always the case. I would avoid being responsible for an ASP testing environment, especially away from its native OS, without much/any knowledge in the area - you could be volunteering yourself for quite a lot of hassle/confusion and complaints from the users when it doesn't work how they'd expect.

Comment: thanks for the advice david. unfortunately i don't have a choice in the matter. :( fortunately its a small team and so there's lots of lee-way for the learning curve. and it's just for one client, so it's not too massive yet. besides - gotta learn sometime! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Apache-ASP: http://www.apache-asp.org/ It's a port of ASP to an Apache module
Not used it myself but looks OK, not sure about performance in live but should be good enough for testing/dev.